# Magento 1.X: _afterSave function for stock item

Tags: magento-1.8, rest-api

I am trying to change "Stock Availability" tab inside "Inventory" tab for configurable product by calling Magento Rest API with standard url.

I see that while calling PUT option to change "Stock Availability", it realized that it calls $stock-save() which in-turn calls _afterSave().

When I see inside this _afterSave function, I see that if I run API for simple product, it run through but if it is configurable product, it struck at parent::_afterSave();.

Just for test purpose, when I commented "parent::_afterSave();" line, it worked beautifully.

Can someone please advise on what am I missing because the same function must be called when we manually save product by going to Magento Dashboard -> Catalog -> Products

[EDIT] : I thought to put code available inside _afterSave():

```
    protected function _afterSave()
{

parent::_afterSave();

/** @var $indexer Mage_Index_Model_Indexer */
$indexer = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer');
if ($this->_processIndexEvents) {
$indexer->processEntityAction($this, self::ENTITY, Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE);
} else {
$indexer->logEvent($this, self::ENTITY, Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE);
}
return $this;
}
```

Your help is really appreciated.

Ashish